# What is a fragment matcher in Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

As titled, I am still unable to figure out what it is and why we need it after reading their [Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/fragments/#fragments-on-unions-and-interfaces).

Apart from that, please also tell me what heuristic fragment matcher means.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Fragments are predefined sets of field selections that you can plug into a query to prevent having to manually specify all the fields you want to return each time.  They are not required, only a tool to use if you find yourself having to repeat a lot of field selections.

Apollo's fragment matcher is not really a utility you have to use, as the docs state it's simply the mechanism that it uses "by default" to match the fragments. Basically how it operates is it determines whether or not the fragment (list of fields) "matches" the data structure being queried if all the fields contained in the fragment do in fact exist on the data structure itself.  "Heuristic" just means a practical, but imperfect, approach to something. This is explained in the docs, stating the situations this mechanism will not work properly in.

This default functionality does not support matching on interfaces and union types, so if you want to query those objects with fragments, then you'd have to make use of an additional utility:

> To support result validation and accurate fragment matching on unions and interfaces, a special fragment matcher called the IntrospectionFragmentMatcher can be used.

However, if you're not introspecting (querying the GraphQL schema for information about itself) these kinds of data structures, that utility is not required.  Again, none of this is required if you're not using fragments (though they can be quite handy!).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry about massively delayed reply